# How to optimize a connection in vba

Tags: vba

I am working with vba, and I am using an excel sheet to find prices using SQL code within vba. Below is an example of how it is done:

```
Sub connection()

Set cn = New ADODB.connection

 Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With
    



End Sub
Function getAddres(ByVal sTableName As String) As String

    With Range(sTableName & "[#All]")
        getAddres = "[" & .Parent.Name & "$" & .Address(False, False) & "]"
    End With

End Function

Function Get_Coeff_1_crit(couv As String, tabelle As String, edit As String, crit1 As String) As Variant

Dim NomFeuille As String, texte_SQL As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strRangeAddress As String

Call connection

    strRangeAddress = getAddres(edit)
  
    texte_SQL = "SELECT  [Coeff] FROM " & strRangeAddress & " WHERE ([Tabelle]=" & Chr(34) & tabelle & Chr(34) & _
    " )  AND (( [Booléen_1] = " & crit1 & " ) OR   ( [Fixe_1] = " & crit1 & " ) OR  (" & crit1 & "  BETWEEN [Min_1] AND [Max_1] ))"
        
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rst = cn.Execute(texte_SQL)
    On Error Resume Next
        Get_Coeff_1_crit = 0
    
    Get_Coeff_1_crit = rst.Fields(0).Value    'ws.Range("N7").CopyFromRecordset Rst

End Function
```

So I have an input of variables and this function looks for the table and correct variable combination.

My issue is that with many functions each establishing a separate connection with the excel sheet, it takes an insane amount of time to process a lot of prices.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a better way, I am rather new at vba, so I was wondering if we can store dataframes within the process like in python or is there a different way to not establish connections each time.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `Call connection` open the connection `cn`?  Have you tried, closing `cn` when finished?  Or opening before this reliance and the closing once complete.  So open `cn` do all what is needed on `cn` then close it.  And closing `rst` for that matter too

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  forgot to add sub connection() but that call connection actually didnt do anything, I commented it out and the function went through, do tell me more about closing cn and rst.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looping over `Get_Coeff_1_crit` repeatedly then I can see why it's bogging down while it's reestablishing that connection each pass.

You'd want to do something like this inside the function,

```
If Not cn is Nothing then 'verify the object is instantiated
    If cn.State = adStateClosed then 'State property tells if it's open
        Call Connection
    End If
End If
'further details on that property - https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_comm_state.asp
```

Comment: forgot to add sub connection() (added it already) but that call connection actually didnt do anything, I commented it out and the function went through.

Comment: The way it works is I have functions with the variables used, then in this function, I might do some changes to the data, then call one of many "crit" functions like the one above, depending on how many variables are being used I use a different "crit" function. I have MANY functions that call these crit funtions and establish a connection with the excel table.

Comment: I wonder if another piece of code is establishing the connection somewhere?    In your function, you could set the Recordsets cursor location to adUseClient and close the connection(making it work like a disconnected dataset!).  `https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rs_cursorlocation.asp`  but just guessing at the moment.